# Renaming index and columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I've a time crucial task to do.

```
In [17]: data[45:73]
Out[18]: 
         Global Data Item       2012       2011       2010       2009        2008        2007        2006
        10  Sub-Data Item       2012       2011       2010       2009        2008        2007        2006
        11  Partial        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
        12  Total      14347      13449      12698      12119       11627       10573       10299
        13  vwx   1.693261   1.573903    1.45203   1.358632    1.274471    1.190117     1.11449
        14  xyz       8617       8702       8878       9009        9247        8980        9276
     -          -          -           -           -           -
```

How can I rename with data.rename(index={???}, columns={???}) the index respectively columns? The current one (Global Data Item (000s)     2012     2011     2010     2009      2008      2007      2006) shall be replaced by ( 10  Sub-Data Item       2012       2011       2010       2009        2008 )

Comment: may be it's me, but question looks really unclear. Have you actually tried `rename()`?

Comment: it looks unclear indeed, but what can't you understand? I want to rename the columns? Right now you can see as a column: Global Data Item... How can I change that and use insted the first line of output code as a column (In this case line 10: Sub-Data Item ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is your task, but from comments I see that you want to use first row of DataFrame as column names. If this is the case, you can do:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':list('xyz')})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  x
1  2  y
2  3  z
>>> df.columns = df.iloc[0]
>>> df
   1  x
0  1  x
1  2  y
2  3  z
```